# SRAPY: (The rules of Me what suits me)

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, scrapy

Code is:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors 

import LinkExtractor

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = 'example.com'

    allowed_domains = ['rabajando.pe']

    start_urls = ['https://www.trabajando.pe/empleos/oferta/939217/Coordinador-de-la-especialidad-de-Contact-Center.html']

    rules = (
        # Extract links matching 'category.php' (but not matching 'subsection.php')
        # and follow links from them (since no callback means follow=True by default).
        #Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('/oferta', ))),
        # Extract links matching 'item.php' and parse them with the spider's method parse_item
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('empleos/oferta/\.html', )), callback='parse_item'),
    )
    print (Rule)
    def parse_item(self, response):
        print ("felicidades")
        self.logger.info('.//div[@class="col-md-12 oferta_row"]', response.url)
        item = scrapy.Item()
        item['Empleo'] = response.xpath('.//div[@itemprop="title"]/h1/text()').extract()
        item['Empresa'] = response.xpath('.//h4[@itemprop="hiringOrganization"]/a/text()').extract()
        item['Sector'] = response.xpath('.//h3[@itemprop="industry"]/text()').extract()
        #yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page_url))
        yield item.load_item()
```

I want to get data in CSV file:

```
scrapy runspider rules.py -o hhhhhh.csv -t csv
```

Comment: You *really* should be thinking about moving to Python 3 if you want help here.

Comment: The question here is not clear. Try to clearly state a question so you can get some answers